# Processing: How to add background music

Tags: processing

I've made a simple little game in Processing, but need some help. I have an mp3 and would like to add it to my app to run in a loop in the background.

Is this possible? Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a sound library. Processing already comes with [Minim](http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/) included.
Have a look in *File > Examples > Libraries > Minim Audio > LoadFile*

```
import ddf.minim.*;

AudioPlayer player;
Minim minim;//audio context

void setup()
{
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player = minim.loadFile("file.mp3", 2048);
  player.play();
}

void draw()
{
}

void stop()
{
  player.close();
  minim.stop();
  super.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Processing's sound library. Go to *Sketch* > *Import* *Library...* > *Add Library...* >

Then search for 'sound' and download the Sound library from the Processing Foundation.

```
import processing.sound.*;
SoundFile file;

 void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
   background(255);

   // Load a soundfile from the /data folder of the sketch and play it back
  file = new SoundFile(this, "sample.mp3");
  file.play();
}      

void draw() {
}
```

Reference can be found here:
https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/index.html